# Error on update event with Outlook rest api

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm using the Outlook REST API for updating recurring events.
I have a weekly event that is repeating every Monday. If I try to edit the time (not the whole Date) of one occurrence sending a PATCH request I get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorPropertyValidationFailure",
    "message": "At least one property failed validation."
  }
}
```

This is my request body:

```
{
"subject":"test",
"body":"<!-- converted from text -->\n<div class=\"PlainText\"> </div>",
"contentType":1,
"locationName":"",
"start":"2018-05-14T13:30:00.000Z",
"end":"2018-05-14T14:30:00.000Z",
"isAllDay":false,
"isPrivate":false,
"attendees":[
{
"name":"...",
"email":"..."
},
{
"name":"...",
"email":"..."
}
],
"reminderMinutes":[
"30"
],
"noReminder":false
}
```

For another account, the same request is working.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You're updating the `start` but not the `end`. Most likely it is failing because you've told it to `start` *after* the `end`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Marc LaFleur! I have updated the post with the whole request payload. Of course, without the data for the attendees.